# Web browser for Slackware 13 that can display today's webpages properly

Tags: linux, web-browser, internet, ssl

This may sound crazy, but I have an oldish dell laptop loaded with Slackware 13 Linux on it (KDE 4) and not much free hard drive space and have been using it now for quite a few years with Opera web browser version 11.62.

For the past year, newer sites have popped up in my search queries and they do not load in that browser because of "unable to establish secure connection". I looked for updates to that browser and the only way I can really update it is to put my system in a complete overhaul (example: ditch slackware 13 and install 14+).

In the meantime, I ended up installing Firefox 43.0 along with upgrading the libraries mentioned on the Firefox 43 manual page. Luckily that works with new web pages but sometimes some pages load so much content in that browser to the point where my system has little memory left for other tasks (because of bugs in firefox).

I still wanted to use Opera because of speed.

The reason why I don't upgrade my computer is because I work with custom-built electronic hardware that uses the standard PC parallel port and the RS232 serial port and new computers don't have that.

Another thing I installed is Wine 1.1.10 and K-meleon 75.1 I think.

Well when i executed it and viewed its "about" page, I get the version "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 K-Meleon/75.1".

Now that browser loads newer pages without the "cannot establish secure connection" error, but the user interface looks ugly (example: I see squares where icons should appear).

I want to keep my computer, but I don't want to do an overhaul on my operating system just to view a new web page (or an old website with their SSL/TLS updated).

So what am I to do?

Should I try a different Wine version? Should I try a different Kmeleon browser version? Should I try another windows browser to emulate in Wine? or should I try a different browser for slackware 13?

I tried installing Vivaldi and that expected newer libraries which suggested a complete system overhaul which I'm not ready to do.